# Is it possible to factor $4x^2-3$?

Tags: factoring

> Is it possible to factor $4x^2-3?$

I honestly can't thing of any way to factor this, but I wanted to be sure it was, in fact, impossible to factor.

### EDIT:

Thanks for the help in the comments. I realize I missed the obvious, so I'll include the answer here:

$$4x^2 - 3 = (2x-\sqrt{3})(2x+\sqrt{3})$$

Comment: In which field?

Comment: difference of squares.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$4x^2-3=(2x-\sqrt3)(2x+\sqrt3)$$

Comment: Do you mind showing me how you got that answer?

Comment: @McB [Difference of squares](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/specfact.htm).

Comment: Never mind! I see it now.

Answer (score 1):

$$4x^2-3=(2x+\sqrt3)(2x-\sqrt3)$$

It can't be factorized further, though.